# Angularjs ng-repeat with new element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying make some test app in anguar.js, but faced with the problem.
My js file contain:

```
live = angular.module('live',[]);
live.controller('printCtrl', function() {
        this.test = [];
        var thizzz = this;

        this.getTest = function() {
            return this.test;
        };

        setInterval(function() {
            thizzz.test.push(Date.now());
        }, 1000);
   }
);
```

My html file contain:

```
<div class="content" ng-app="live">
    <div ng-controller="printCtrl as print">
        <div ng-repeat="t in print.getTest()">
             {{t}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But i don't see anything. Why?

------------- UPDATE ---------------

I'm change my js file like this:

```
live = angular.module('live',[]);
live.controller('printCtrl', function() {
        this.test = [1, 2, 3];
        var thizzz = this;

        this.getTest = function() {
            console.log('INSIDE');
            return this.test;
        };

        setInterval(function() {
            thizzz.test.push(Date.now());
        }, 1000);
   }
);
```

and html without any changes.

I don't see anythink in HTML files, but i see in console, how angular call 2 times getTest function.

Comment: can you see the value in test array? it seems empty to me. Please be sure you are actually executing the code pushing into test array.

Comment: if i'm add console.log(thizzz.test) inside setInterval function, i see new elements add into it. But angular don't want reflect into HTML

Comment: Code seems fine to me. Can you add one default object into the array? So we can detect where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see here : http://jsbin.com/munal/2/edit

```
<div ng-controller="printCtrl" ng-init="printList=getTest()">

    <div ng-repeat="t in test">
         {{t}}
    </div>
</div>

  </div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('printCtrl', function($scope){

        $scope.test = [];


        this.getTest = function() {
            return this.test;
        };

        setInterval(function() {
           $scope.test.push(Date.now());
          $scope.$apply();
        }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, your variant work fine, but i'm don't understand why my code doesn't work. I think angular autodetect new element inside array, but without apply i don't see any changes...

Comment: @user2024300 if you use setInterval you need call  $scope.$apply() because otherwise angular don't now about changes. You can use  $interval like in Raghav answer and in that case you don't have to call  $scope.$apply(). I hope that will help

Comment: what if i get new element using WebSocket? I need $scope.$apply to?

Comment: depends how do you call WebSocket

Comment: socket.on('message', function() {$scope.test.push(message);});

Comment: @user2024300 but you still want to call it in time loop ? if yes please follow rules from second comment

Comment: now, only in WebSocket. I'm using setInterval only for test case

Answer (score 2):

If we use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` in an AngularJS application we also need to use $scope.$apply() to ensure that any changes to the scope will be reflected elsewhere (i.e. data-bound in a view).

AngularJS provides a handy wrapper for this: $timeout() - it does the $apply() call for us so we don't have to.

```
$interval(function () {
    thizzz.test.push(Date.now());
}, 1000);
```

see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VPVF6/

Answer (score 1):

You need to init a variable first in order to get the list and then use that scope variable

```
<div class="content" ng-app="live">
    <div ng-controller="printCtrl as print" ng-init="printList=getTest()">
        <div ng-repeat="t in printList">
             {{t}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller is required to have $interval service so that no $apply is required

```
$interval(function() {
    $scope.test.push(Date.now());
 }, 1000);
```